# Prolog query that checks through list

Tags: prolog

I'm pretty new to prolog and while learning it I stumbled upon a problem that I'm having. I basically have a few database facts. They are:

```
book(year(1937), title([of,mice,and,men]), rating_out_of_ten(9)).
book(year(2008), title([the,hunger,games]), rating_out_of_ten(8)).
```

I'm am trying to query the books that have the word "of" in the title. This is what I attempted:

```
book(year, title, rating_out_of_ten), member(of, title).
```

It returns false when I do this. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm new to the prolog too but I think I know the solution:

1. In your query you are actually using the wrong predicate, it should be `book`, instead of `movie`
2. The query should look like this:

   ```
   book(X,title(Y),Z), member(of,Y)
   ```

Arguments have to be capitalized (they have to be variables), however to reach elements of the list you have to use list's name and then a variable, like this:

```
title(Y)
```

so you can use `Y` in the application of the `member` predicate.

Comment: or `?- book(_, title(T), _), member(of,T).` if you want the results to only reflect the values for the title.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that variable names must start with a capital letter (or underscore).  Also, are you really querying on `movie` when your facts are `book`?

You could try:

```
?- book(year(Y), title(T), rating_out_of_ten(R)), member(of, T).
```

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo.. Thanks!